# Activating next input field in form on enter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Order entry form contains product code and quantity columns in multiple rows and delete button
(-) in end of every row. It contains also add button in first column and after form.

Pressing enter key should set focus to next text or numeric input field (product code or quantity), skipping buttons.

I tried code below is used but enter key is ignored.

Chrome debugger shows that line `$(this).next('input').focus()` is executed but 
focus() call does not have any effect.

jquery, jquery-mobile, ASP.NET MVC4 are used

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="/Scripts/jquery/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div data-role="page" data-theme="a">
 <div data-role="content">
<script>
  $(function () {
    $('#inputform').on('keydown', 'input', function (event) {
      if (event.which == 13) {
        $(this).next('input').focus();
        event.preventDefault();
      }
    });
  });
</script>
<form id='inputform' method="post" 
   action ="/Detail/SaveFullDocument?_entity=DokG&amp;_id=0">
  <fieldset>
<div class='form-field' >
<label class='form-label' for='Tasudok'>Order number</label>
<input class='ui-widget-content ui-corner-all form-fullwidth'  id='Tasudok' name='Tasudok'  value=''  maxlength='25' /></div>

  <input type="hidden" name="_rows" />

  <table id="tableId">
    <tr>
      <th>Product code</th>
      <th>Quantity</th>
      <td>
        <input type="button" value="+" onclick="addRow('tableId')" /></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="Toode" /></td>
      <td>
        <input type="number" name="Kogus" /></td>
      <td>
        <input type="button" value="-" onclick="deleteRow(this)" /></td>
    </tr>
  </table>

    <input type="button" value="+" onclick="addRow('tableId')" />
    <input type="submit" value='Save order' />
</form>

    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that the next input is sometimes a button. Here is a JS Fiddle with a possible solution:

http://jsfiddle.net/hxZSU/1/

I've added a data attribute to the html elements that are inputs for the user. The attribute also contains an incrementing index so that you can control the order of the elements receiving focus.

Here are the HTML changes:

```
<input class='ui-widget-content ui-corner-all form-fullwidth' data-index="1" id='Tasudok' name='Tasudok' value='' maxlength='25' />
<input type="text" name="Toode" class="my-input" data-index="2" />
<input type="number" name="Kogus" data-index="3" />
```

Here is the new JavaScript event that will move between the input fields. It will determine the index of the element is currently being edited by using $(event.target).attr('data-index'). It increments the index and selects the next element using this.

```
$('#inputform').on('keydown', 'input', function (event) {
    if (event.which == 13) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var $this = $(event.target);
        var index = parseFloat($this.attr('data-index'));
        $('[data-index="' + (index + 1).toString() + '"]').focus();
    }
});
```

Comment: This works great. I suggest adding input[type=text] as selector so enter key worked on submit (or use button as submit).

Answer (score 4):

### html bit

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

</style>
</head>
<body>

<form id= 'form' >
      <input onkeydown='handleEnter(event)' placeholder="field 1" /><br>
      
      <input onkeydown='handleEnter(event)' placeholder="field 2" /><br>
      <input placeholder="field 3" />
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

### Jvascript bit

```js
function handleEnter(event) {
   if (event.key==="Enter") {
      const form = document.getElementById('form')
      const index = [...form].indexOf(event.target);
      form.elements[index + 1].focus();
      //event.preventDefault();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot or want to avoid to modify your inputs html, you can use the following snippet based on jQuery:

```
$('#inputform').on('keydown', 'input', function (event) {
    if (event.which == 13) {
        var $allInputs = $('#inputform input, #inputform select')
        var $this = $(event.target);
        var index = $allInputs.index($this);
        if (index < $allInputs.length - 1) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $allInputs[index+1].focus()
        }
    }
});
```

The if-case is implemented to not trigger the preventDefault() for the last input that is probably a submit.