# Getting focus on next input element anywhere on the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<div>
  <table><tr><td><input type="text"/></td></tr></table>
</div>
<div>
  <table><tr><td><input type="text"/></td></tr></table>
</div>
```

Consider this section for instance.
There are two textboxes (anywhere on a page).
I'm trying to set focus from the first input to the immediate next input when the user presses Enter key.
How would I achieve this in JQuery?

Comment: Just a small note, you know that this is counter-intuitive right? Normally using **Enter** within a form submits the forum, while pressing  **Tab** usually brings you to the next field in the form. If you're going to change that behaviour, people might be confused.

Comment: Yes yes, I'm fully aware of that. The enter press i mentioned was just to give an idea of when i'm trying to do this.

Comment: If it's just about the idea and not the key use **tabindex** and the tab key !

    `<div>
      <table><tr><td><input type="text" tabindex="1"/></td></tr></table>
    </div>
    <div>
      <table><tr><td><input type="text" tabindex="2"/></td></tr></table>
    </div>`

Comment: tabindex will be your solution try it

Comment: @VforVendetta - it's not. He said `enter`, not `tab`.

Comment: @JayMee he said *The enter press i mentioned was just to give an idea of when i'm trying to do this.*
So **enter** is just a key as **tab**

Comment: For the sake of the initial question asked, lets just assume it is the Enter keypress I'm looking for.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Activating next input field in form on enter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19610357/activating-next-input-field-in-form-on-enter)

Comment: @Shanzid 
As you wish ^^
HTML provide built-in facilities, no need for code if you use **tab** 
I'll still leave a demo : https://jsfiddle.net/99ho0sqr/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this this will help you

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input').on("keypress", function(e) {

    if (e.which == 13) {
      var tab = $(this).attr("tabindex") + 1
      $("input[tabindex=" + tab + "]").focus();
    }
  });


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="text" tabindex="1" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
<div>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="text" tabindex="2" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: parseInt required

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `.keypress` event of jQuery.

**HTML**

```
<div>
  <table><tr><td><input type="text" id="first" autofocus/></td></tr></table>
</div>
<div>
  <table><tr><td><input type="text" id="second"/></td></tr></table>
</div>
```

**jQuery block**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#first').keypress(function(e){
    if(e.keyCode ==13)
    {
      $('#second').focus();
    }
  })
});
```

**Working DEMO** : https://jsfiddle.net/ne403qyb/

Hope this helps!

Comment: This wouldn't be really efficient in my case since my page would have around 20 textboxes and following this approach would mean that I'd have to assign the function to each and every textbox.

Comment: `$(this).next('input.text').focus();` will do the trick.  Check the updated fiddle here => https://jsfiddle.net/ne403qyb/1/

Comment: the input elements are not siblings. The .next() would not work in that case.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('input[type=text]').keypress(function(e) {
      if (e.keyCode == 13) {

        if ($(this).attr('class') === "last") {
          $('input[type=text]').eq(0).focus()
        } else {

          $('input[type=text]').closest('input[type=text]').focus();
        }
      }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="#">
 
  <input type="text"  />
  
  <input type="text" class="last" />
</form>
```

Comment: Still it doesn't go back to previous control if the current textbox is the last one!

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(document).on("keydown", "#Textbox1", function(e) {
      var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which; 
      if (keyCode == 13) {                       
        e.preventDefault(); 
        $("#Textbox2").focus();
      }
    });
```

Woking [**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/AravindhGopi/kce9v4ks/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this :)

```js
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
    if(e.which == 13) {
        var focusElem = document.activeElement;
        var nextInput = $(focusElem).next().attr('id');
        $("#" + nextInput).focus();
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="input_1" />
<input type="text" id="input_2" />
<input type="text" id="input_3" />
<input type="text" id="input_4" />
```

Comment: In my question strictly showed that the input elements are not siblings.

Answer (score 0):

You can give all of you input elements a class(you can do the same by input text tag in case you do not have the input type text element in your document on which you do not want the focus  ) and can find the next input element having same class.

```js
$(".test").keypress(function(e) {
    var inputs = $(".test");
    if(e.which == 13) {   
    var $next = inputs.filter(":gt(" + inputs.index(this) + ")").first();
    $next.focus();
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <table><tr><td><input class ="test"type="text"/></td></tr></table>
</div>
<div>
  <table><tr><td><input class="test" type="text"/></td></tr></table>
</div>
<div>
  <table><tr><td><input class="test" type="text"/></td></tr></table>
</div>
<div>
  <table><tr><td><input class="test" type="text"/></td></tr></table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try other alternative as [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qyqrwor8/),

HTML :

```
<div>
  <table><tr><td><input type="text" class='inputs'/></td></tr></table>
</div>
<div>
  <table><tr><td><input type="text" class='inputs'/></td></tr></table>
</div>
```

JS :

```
$(document).on("input", "input", function(e){
   if(e.which == 13){
       $(this).next('.inputs').focus();
   }
});
```